# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "int4range" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations, django-database

First time using PostgreSQL specific database fields, more specifically `IntegerRangeField`. Using Django 1.8.7, PostgreSQL 9.1.13, Psycopg2 2.6.1 and Python 2.7.3 on a Debian virtual machine. Running the migration that adds the `IntegerRangeField` to a model raises:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "int4range" does not exist`

Do I have to install any module or extension in PostgreSQL in order to use range fields? (I know there is an extension that must be loaded to use `HStoreField`)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range fields in postgresql are available from version 9.2 (as mentioned [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html), they were introduced in 9.2), so you can't use them on 9.1.13 because they aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

[Range data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html) were added in PostgreSQL 9.2. You are using 9.1.13.

Comment: Thanks, and here are some tips to get the required PostgreSQL working on Debian wheezy http://www.pontikis.net/blog/postgresql-9-debian-7-wheezy